# Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath not found in CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {}

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jaxb, java-11

While using JAXB-API with CompletableFuture.runAsync gives error for module not found while if I use the same function without CompletableFuture it works fine

So, do you have any dependency here that it won't work with async functions ?

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() => {
  testFunc()
})

public void testFunc() {
----
Performs some task using JAXB 
----
}
```

this gives module not found exception, while

```
testFunc();

public void testFunc() {
----
Performs some task using JAXB 
----
}
```

This works, why is that so ?

Answer (score 0):

It's works for me

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
               testFunc()
        }, pool).join();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.